# AICc and K for categorical factors and interactions

Tags: r, mixed-model, categorical-data, interaction, aic

I am new to multimodel inference. I am trying to create a model that has multiple categorical factors and possible interactions. For example say that my model is...

> Y ~ X1 + factor(X2) + factor(X3)

say each factor has two possible categories. R is only giving me AIC in my summary output. When calculating AICc would K be 3 or 5?

also, if I have a potential interaction as in...

> Y ~ X1 * X2 + X3

would K be 3 or 4? Also what do I do if there is an interaction? Do I just stop there or can I continue with analysis leaving the interaction term in the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly, "none of the above".

I assume that in your question, $K$ is defined the same as $k$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc).

Every parameter that is in the model counts. So for every level of a factor (above the first), add one. For every factor-level-by-factor-level interaction term that has a parameter estimate, add one. And add one for the intercept and *another one for the estimate of $\sigma^2\,$*!

When comparing raw AICs it doesn't matter if some parameters are omitted from *every* model (so if two models both fail to count $\sigma^2$ it wouldn't matter, since it won't change the difference in AIC), but it *does* matter for AICc; you have to count properly there.

---

As is explained in the help on R's `AIC` function, that function will give you the df (i.e. $K$) if you supply it with more than one model:

```
 carsfit=lm(dist~speed,cars)
 carsfitf=lm(dist~cut(speed,seq(0,max(speed),5)),cars)
 AIC(carsfit,carsfitf)
         df      AIC
carsfit   3 419.1569
carsfitf  6 428.5270
```

Note 3 df for a linear regression (intercept, slope, variance).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! So in my above example are you saying that (excluding interactions) in the above example with factors (2 levels each) k would be 5 + 1 for the intercept + 1 for the error. So k=7?

Comment: No, it should be 5. 1 for intercept + 1 for X1 +1 for levels of factor(X2) above the first, + 1 for levels of factor(X3) above the first + 1 for $\sigma^2$. Supply the models with and without interactions to a single call to `AIC()` to check them both.

Comment: Sorry. Now I'm confused. :P I'm talking about the very top example. Let me ask you this. If each categorical variable had 3 levels, would it be 7 then? Are you basically saying that a 2 factor variable only "costs" me k=1?

Comment: correct - for a factor with $g$ levels, there's $g-1$ parameters; the base (or *reference*) level is taken up by the intercept. Look at the output from `summary` on your fitted model.